# How to priortize execution of xml tags in txmlMap using talend

Tags: sql-server, talend

I am new to Talend and I am facing problems while working with txmlmap.

I have a XML file and I need to insert the data from that XML into SQL Server. I have made connection in Talend to connect to SQL Server, however I am facing some problems while prioritizing the XML tags.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <entry name="opertaion-round-title">
        <valstr>ROUND 1</valstr>
    </entry>
    <entry name="site">
        <valstr>SITE NAME</valstr>
    </entry>
    <entry name="plant">
        <valstr>PLANT NAME</valstr>
    </entry>
    <entry name="opertaion-area">
        <valstr>G AREA</valstr>
    </entry>
</data>
```

I am using `txmlMap` to pass data from XML to the database. I have four tables. I need to put the values based on the entry tag (name).

```
SITES,
PLANTS,
OPERATING_AREAS,
OPERATING_ROUNDS
```

I need to put site value to SITES table, plant value to PLANTS table, operation-area value to OPERATING_AREAS table and operation-round-title to OPERATING_ROUNDS table.

I am successfully getting the values in the table, however I first want to insert site value to SITES table followed by plants value in PLANTS table then OPERATING_AREAS and OPERATING_ROUNDS table.

The problem which I am facing is that whatever value is first present in xml its inserting to that table. i.e in this case its first inserting the values to OPERATING_ROUNDS table because the first tag in the xml is `<entry name="opertaion-round-title">`. But I want in the following order

```
SITES
PLANTS
OPERATING_AREAS
OPERATING_ROUNDS
```

So Is there anyway in which we can set priority of execution of tags in txmlMap so that irrespective of whatever tag comes first It will process the tags based on the priority which we have defined.

Please find attached screen shot of

[image: design of components]

and

[image: txmlMap configuration]

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you might need to overthink the way you think you are processing data:

- First, you will loop over an XML file (if there are more entries in the `data` section)
- Then you will do some mapping. Usually, this happens in the input component. So this is where you'd say "I've got a row variable called SITES and it should be filled with the contents of data/sites/valstr". There is no picture of the mapping, so this is hard to guess
- You row would be filled with 4 values, being those 4 you wrote down
- Then you simply split those into the four buckets you created (the output components into the database)

Meaning, there is no priortization needed. You only need to make sure that the mapping is correct and then you might be able to do that in a tMap as well.